# elegant comparing strings in two NSArrays

Tags: objective-c

Dear all. We have 2 arrays(currentCarriers and companyList with strings inside. A final solution have to be array, which exclude same string from first array.
Bellow is a my solutions, but probably two for loops is not like cocoa style. Maybe somebody can suggest something better?

```
for (NSString *carrier in currentCarriers) {
    for (NSString *company in  companyList)
    {
        if ([company isEqualToString:carrier]) [removedCompanies addObject:company];        }
}    

NSMutableArray *companiesForAdd = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:companyList];
[companiesForAdd removeObjectsInArray:removedCompanies];
```

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: O_o That's the worst implementation possible for this common problem (sorry Alex, don't mean to insult). Best solution would be a set difference, BTW.

Comment: @DarkDust - I thought removeObjectsInArray would do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: We don't know how it's done internally (that's on purpose), e.g. they could could turn the arrays into sets for large arrays etc. pp. Chances are Apple's implementation is faster than the naive one :-) Also, at least a `break` in the inner would be nice ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Turn one list into a mutable array and then use `removeObjectsInArray:`, as in:

```
foo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:currentCarriers];
[foo removeObjectsInArray:companyList];
// foo now contains only carriers that are not in the company list.
```

**Edit:**

Alternative with set difference (but possible slower in most cases due to the copying/allocating):

```
NSMutableSet *foo = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:currentCarriers];
[foo minusSet:[NSSet setWithArray:companyList]];
```

This might be faster for bigger lists, but you lose the ordering (if any).

Comment: That's not correct. i tried it. bcs objects in two arrays not same, it's a different strings from two different classes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Do you mean `[string1 isEqual:string2]` yields false in your case, even though both have the same content ?

Comment: as i understand, when i try to using directly array's to do removeObjects, objects there must have equal (same object's with same pointers). This is not as i have right now - i have arrays with different strings inside, string there is a different objects. So when i try to removeObject from there, that's nothing removing.

Comment: @Alex no, they do not need to have same pointers. If the objects you are comparing are of specific types such as NSString, these have custom implementations of the "isEqual" selector, which will call the "isEqualToString" in this case, hence why this code works.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can get rid of the inner loop using `-containsObject:` method of NSArray, something like

```
for (NSString *carrier in currentCarriers) {
    if ([companyList containsObject:carrier])
        [removedCompanies addObject:company];       
}    

NSMutableArray *companiesForAdd = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:companyList];
[companiesForAdd removeObjectsInArray:removedCompanies];
```

Comment: same thing there, object's can't be equal (see my post before)

Comment: array 1 have NSString objects 1,2,3, array 2 have NSString objects 3.4.5. When i try to using removeObjects method, it's (how i understand, compare object and don't look inside strings). Maybe it wrong, but i was not success in that way and found 2 loops was which working now.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two options

- If you worry about performance, then you can sort arrays and then create a result in one pass.
- If you don't worry, then just filter the `currentCarriers` using `[companyList containsObject:]`